# al editar cliente, me genera error en php y xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema_venta_basico-master\sistema\editar_cliente.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema_venta_basico-master\sistema\editar_cliente.php(18): mysqli_fetch_array(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema_venta_basico-master\sistema\editar_cliente.php on line 18

```
$result = 0;
if (is_numeric($doc) and $doc != 0) {

  $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM cliente where (doc = doc' AND idcliente != $idcliente)");
  $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  $resul = mysqli_num_rows($query);
}

if ($resul >= 1) {
```

Comment: Ese error suele ocurrir cuando la consula SQL falla. Aquí no hay ninguna duda de que tu consulta tiene un error de sintaxis, falta una comilla simple antes de `doc`  y, supongo que deberías usar la variable `$doc` ahí, cosa que no haces. Es más, siendo que `doc` al parecer es numérico, la consulta debería quedar así: `$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM cliente where (doc = $doc AND idcliente != $idcliente)");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese error suele ocurrir cuando la consula SQL falla. Aquí no hay ninguna duda de que tu consulta tiene un error de sintaxis, faltaría una comilla simple antes de `doc`.

Pero, viendo que antes haces una verificación sobre si `$doc`  es numérico, supongo que la columna `doc` en la base de datos es numérica, en cuyo caso, no sería necesario rodear el valor por comillas simples. Además, intuyo que deberías usar la variable `$doc` como criterio del `WHERE`, cosa que tampoco haces.

Si modificas la consulta de este modo debería funcionar:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM cliente where (doc = $doc AND idcliente != $idcliente)");
```

Si la columna `doc` no fuera numérica:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM cliente where (doc = '$doc' AND idcliente != $idcliente)");
```

#### Nota sobre la seguridad

Tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Considera usar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese gravísimo agujero de seguridad.

Comment: efectivamente era el error, Agradezco mucho su ayuda.